# How should you fit ANOVA and linear regression models, if the equal variance assumption is violated?

Tags: regression, self-study, anova, data-transformation, heteroscedasticity

This is my topic for the paper I'm working on for an undergrad stats class. It's supposed to be 20 pages... and I'll be honest, I understand very little beyond the basics and am over my head.

- From what I understand, there several common tests to test if the assumption is violated... Levene's / Bartlett's, etc... and if the assumption is in fact violated, there are basically 2 paths you can take... (non-linear) transformations, or weighted least squares?
- What are some of the common things to consider when choosing whether to go with transformations / weighted least squares? What are the most commonly used transformations?

Comment: What do you mean that this is for a paper? Are you writing a paper on heteroscedasticity?

Comment: Guess I should have worded things better. The paper is on the topic of "How should you fit ANOVA and linear regression models, if the equal variance assumption is violated?"

(that topic, word for word, was assigned to me by my professor)

Comment: Our policy is not to provide direct answers to questions that pertain to people's class assignments, but to provide hints to help people get unstuck. To understand the process more fully, see the [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `[self-study]` tag. You should probably be able to learn a lot by searching the site & reading relevant threads, though.

Comment: What class is this, I wonder? Who assigns a 20 page paper on how to fit an ANOVA w/ heteroscedasticity? I've never heard of such a thing. Are you a statistics major at Harvey Mudd?

Comment: it's STATS 3093: Probability and Mathematical Statistics II. (A third year course at a so-so Canadian university with an awful stats department). I'm a math major, (statistics minor). It's the 4th stats (13-14 week) course I've taken. The course had nothing to do with the topic, it was just sort of a project to do something that's (mostly) new to us to try to push us. Heteroscedasticity was in no way covered in any course I've taken.

Answer (score 1):

One of the key assumptions of an ANOVA is that of an equal spread of residuals. You can normalise these residuals by using a transformation function. Hint: search Wikipedia for the most common transformations. These are usually just multiplied by the variable or raised to a certain power. Try playing around these transformations until you see your residuals normalise on a histogram/normal score plot.  But be careful interpreting the results, because it's on a multiplicative scale and not a linear scale once you transform it.

There's no "correct" transformation as long as it normalises the residuals.

There's a good software called ARC that does the visualisation for you. You can download it for free. Just Google Arc Stats Software. You'll see it on the University of Minnesota web page.